# Azure web app is not fetching values from configuration Tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I developed an asp.net core API that saves images to the Azure blob storage account and inserts blob URI in cosmos DB.

In my local, it is working as expected. (I am reading storage account and cosmos Db connection strings from appsetting.json in my local).

I deployed my service in the Azure web app and this time I want to read those connections from the azure web app configuration(Settings --> Configuration Tab) instead of reading from appsettings.json. So I provided the configuration in azureweb app itself as mentioned in the screenshot.

[image]

But when I call my endpoint it is showing the following error (Saying my connection string is null)

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Azure.Storage.StorageConnectionString.Parse(String connectionString)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient..ctor(String connectionString, BlobClientOptions options)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient..ctor(String connectionString)
   at BikesIsland.API.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ConfigureServices>b__0(IServiceProvider factory) in D:\a\BikesIsland\BikesIsland\BikesIsland.API\Startup.cs:line 64
```

Here is my appsetting.json structure

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": ""
  },
  "CosmosDbSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "",
    "DatabaseName": "bikes-island",
    "BikeContainerName": "Bikes",
    "EnquiryContainerName": "Enquiry",
    "BikeReservationContainerName": "bike-reservation",
    "BikePartitionKeyPath": "/id",
    "EnquiryPartitionKeyPath": "/id",
    "BikeReservationPartitionKeyPath": "/bikeId"

  },
  "BlobStorageSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "",
    "ContainerName": "bikesimages"
  },
  "ServiceBusSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "",
    "QueueName": "reservation"
  }

}
```

Please help me to resolve the above error. As I am completely new to the azure web app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you setup the Host in Program.cs? Do you use the default builder?

Comment: @juunas, I edited my question and added the source code repo GitHub for reference.

Comment: I use `:` as navigation  separator instead of `__`. My app service plan is Windows.

Comment: Why are you building Configuration in so many places? Let the default host builder do it and accept the config through dependency injection where you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are reading value of `BlobStorageSettings:ConnectionString` [here](https://github.com/akhil117/BikesIsland/blob/a4642a2e45e646b57dda3e0eabbbb159f1a6bd03/BikesIsland.API/Startup.cs#L62) in your code:

```
var value = Configuration.GetSection("BlobStorageSettings:ConnectionString").Value;
```

While you have added `BlobStorageSettings__ConnectionString` in your App Settings. please change that to `BlobStorageSettings:ConnectionString` and it shall work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @singhh-msft suggested I also updated the startup.cs file

Here is the following code snippet I updated in the startup constructor

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

and I updated the configuration tab in settings as @singhh-msft suggested

Pls refer below screenshot
[image]

After these changes, it started working to me